# Selenium-webdriver on Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

Is there a setting where you can update the homepage when it opens a new browser?

For newer version of `selenium-webdriver`, it actually opens a blank page. This is what i need right now, but i cant use it since the website im working is on `1.8.7`.

Im having problems with the older version because it opens a page and timeouts because I'm using a machine without an internet. (I need to use this machine)

I'm currently working with `phantomJS` btw. I checked it with `firefox`, it opens mozilla.org even though my default page in`firefox` is a blank page.

The `.start(url,browser)` doesn't work since it will open first the browser before going to the `url`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fine with `phantomjs`. I thought it was an issue with an older version. In phantomjs, it really opens a blank page.

Newer version of `selenium-webdriver`, starts firefox with a blank page. While the lower version I use still have issues firefox.